# How do we add values into the below struct ? Am a newbie here! Thanks in advance!

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract DriverRegister {

    enum CarType {mini, micro, prime}

    struct Driver {
        string name;
        uint phno;
        uint licenceno;
        bool isDriverRegistered;
        CarType cartypes;
        uint index;
    }

    mapping(address => Driver) public driverStructs;
    address[] public drivers;

    function registerDriver(string memory _name, uint _phno, uint _licenceno) public {

    }
}
```

In such a way, that it can be retrieved using a unique id? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of syntaxes to initialize structs.

Directly pass the values as parameter.

```
driverStructs[msg.sender] = Driver(_name, _phno, _licenceno, _isDriverRegistered, _cartypes, _index);
```

Or pass the values as object.

```
driverStructs[msg.sender] = Driver({
    name: _name,
    phno: _phno,
    licenceno: _licenceno,
    isDriverRegistered: _isDriverRegistered,
    cartypes: _cartypes,
    index: _index
});
```

I recommend using the 2nd approach. As here you don't have to worry about the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like that?

```
function registerDriver(string memory _name, uint _phno, uint _licenceno) public{
  driverStructs[msg.sender] = Driver(_name, _phno, _licenceno, isDriverRegistered, cartypes[x], index);
}
```

I'm a newbie myself, so take it with a grain of salt. But normally that's the way to do it.